# How is davening affected by the observance of י"ט שבט (for those who observe it)?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

For those who observe [י"ט שבט](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27166697#27166697), how is *davening* affected?

- I am aware that *Tachanun* is omitted, but is it also omitted at *mincha* on *erev Yod-Teth Shevat*?
- Is [Psalm 20](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2620.htm) recited at *shacharit*?
- Is *hallel* recited? If so, is it said with or without a *berakha*?
- Is there an *al hanisim* or *ya'aleh v'yavo* addition to *shmoneh esrei* and/or *birkat hamazon*?  If so, does accidentally omitting it require *shmoneh esrei* and/or *birkat hamazon* to be repeated?

I am not planning on confirming what I learn here with my rabbi, so please make sure that your answer is correct.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: +1 for "I am not planning on confirming what I learn here with my rabbi, so please make sure that your answer is correct."

Comment: http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/kitveyet/mahanaim/shulhan/haberman.htm Shulchan Arukh Even HaEzer was completed on 19 Shevat 5717

Comment: I saw this on the sidebar. Now that I'm reading it .. I don't get it at all. What's the deal with 19 Shevat? What occurred that you make a parody of it?

Comment: @DanF 19 Shevat is the date when SE allowed us to add the disclaimer to the sidebar of MY saying that we don't offer halachic advice and that you should ask practical questions with your rabbi. More context is in the first link in the question. (Also DoubleAA's answer actually gives a pretty good explanation of the Yat be'Shevat story)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the traditional insertion is:

על הניסים...
בימי יצחק משה אבינו וה[מוד](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators)ים  שוטרינו במי יודע תובב"א כשעמד עליהם ה[כלבים](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Internet,_nobody_knows_you%27re_a_dog) בקשו לפסוק הלכה על פי הכתוב באתר בלי לעשות
כילא"ר כדין, ולא שמעו שוג-תשע והדֶבים למחות במעשים הרעים האלה. ואתה ברחמיך הרבים הפרת את עצתם כהרף עין בהעמדת הודעה לרבים ומסרת הכלבים בידי רבניהם הקרובים אליהם לקבל פסיקתם השייך להם. ואחך כך באו בניך ל[בם](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27166697#27166697) וקבעו יום י"ט שבט להודות לך ולדלג תחנון לשמך הגדול.‏

As with all other Al HaNissim insertions, one would not need to repeat if they forgot to include this.

Comment: Shouldn't that be כילו"ר?

Comment: @Scimonster Rinnat Yisrael does have it your way.

Comment: In fact old manuscripts have the spelling קילא״ר, an anagram of א קליר. This is taken to be an indication that this *nusach* was composed by none other than [R. Elazar HaKalir](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleazar_ben_Killir).

Comment: Vowelizing this would be considerably more enjoyable

Answer (score 6):

Being that the holiday is celebrated in honor of the long-awaited reminder to [ask your rabbi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146), we cannot answer this definitely on this site. Ask your rabbi.

Answer (score 3):

As one that observes it, and many of my friends do too, we drink quite a bit of whiskey, and thus we do not daven at all.

I was taught how to observe this holiday by Rabbi Trink Mer & Rabbi Johnnie Walker.