# PTIJ: in nusach Yodeya, where in the t'filah do we acknowledge the fourth patriarch?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

The first blessing in the *Amidah* is, of course, *avot*, where we acknowledge the patriarchs.  What is the version of this text in [*nusach* Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/100239/472)?  Where do we acknowledge our [additional patriarch](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164436/162102)?  Do we say *elokei Avraham, elokei Yitzchak, elokei Yaakov, elokei Yitzchak*, to preserve the order?  Or is that confusing and instead we say ...*elokei Yitzchakim*?  Or maybe we add *elokei Yitzchak Moshe*?  Or do we not modify this passage, and we instead acknowledge the last patriarch somewhere else?

I've been unable to obtain a Yodeyan *siddur*, but I'm hoping that one of you can tell me what the correct practice is.

(I'm aware that there are other places in *davening* where we list the patriarchs.  I'm focusing on this very prominent one, but a general answer that applies to all of them, if such exists, would be great.)

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Asked with hours to spare!  (Why oh why did I only think of this *now*?)

Comment: "Your title shall be Moderator. No longer shall you be called Patriarch." Shabbat Shalom!

Comment: Except that "no longer called" didn't exactly happen in that other case, so why should we assume it here?  Shabbat shalom!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Did you ever wonder why it's "Elohei Avraham Elohei Yitzchak **V** elohei Yaakov"? Why don't we say Velohei both times like how Vav is used repeatedly in Tanakh (eg. Gen 25 ויאכל וישת ויקם וילך ויבז)?

It's because we specifically want to connect Yitzchak with a following name of Hashem. What's the connection? Hashem spelled backwards in Hebrew is Moshe. The hint was there all along, since God knew about Mi Yodeya long ago. He even hinted to it many times in Tanakh.